# How to scroll to an element with React

Tags: html, css, reactjs, frontend

I'm feeling stupid cause i did the entire site but I'm stuck trying to make the navlinks scroll in the components of the same page.

My App.js

```
import Header from './components/Header';
import Intro from './components/Intro';
import Experience from './components/Experience';
import Skills from './components/Skills';
import Projects from './components/Projects';
import Arts from './components/Arts';
import Graduation from './components/Graduation';
import Footer from './components/Footer';

import styled from 'styled-components';

const AppContainer = styled.div`
    width: 100%;
`;

function App() {
  return (
    <AppContainer>
      <Header />
      <Intro />
      <Experience />
      <Skills />
      <Projects />
      <Arts />
      <Graduation />
      <Footer />
    </AppContainer>
  )
}

export default App;
```

My Header

```
function HeaderMenu() {
    return (
        <ul>
            <li><a href='#projects'>Projects</a></li>
            <li><a href='#skills'>Skills</a></li>
            <li><a href='#contact'>Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
    )
};

export default HeaderMenu;
```

What i already have tried and didn't worked: use the hashtag (like html-css), "react-scroll", useRef.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved.

I needed to install this:

```
npm install --save react-router-hash-link
```

On App.Js

```
    import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';

    function App() {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Header />
      <Intro />
      <Experience />
      <Skills />
      <Projects />
      <Arts />
      <Graduation />
      <Footer />
    </BrowserRouter>
  )
}
```

I put an **id** on every component i wanted to use.

```
<ExperienceContainer id="experience">
<ProjectsContainer id="projects">
```

On header

```
import { HashLink as Link } from 'react-router-hash-link';

const StyledLink = styled(Link)`
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #000000;
`

function Header() {
    return (
        <ul>
            <li><StyledLink to="#experience">Experience</StyledLink></li>
            <li><StyledLink to="#projects">Projects</StyledLink></li>
        </ul>
    )
};

export default Header;
```

Hope it helps somebody new to React.

Answer (score 0):

You can try `overflow-x: scroll;`

doc: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow-x

Comment: The problem is not the scrollbar.
I just need to make my navbar work correctly, for example: click on the 'Contact' link of the header and the browser scrolls to the section where have the component 'Contact'.

In HTML/CSS we just put the id on the DIV and the problem is solved with a simple <a href='#contact'>, but i can't have the same result in React.